# ObjectAnimator not pausing when application goes to to background

Tags: android, android-animation, android-lifecycle

I have some ObjectAnimators running. I want this animators to pause when application goes to background (onPause is called). Must I do this manually? I recall I read somewhere that ObjectAnimators auto-handled their pausing/resume when application went from foreground to background and the other way.

So, the question is: When using ObjectAnimators must the user handle pausing/resuming manually?

Cheers.